# Text selection with keyboard in Okular

Tags: linux, pdf, pdf-reader, okular

Is it possible to select text in a PDF with Okular using the keyboard?
Something in the lines of:

- Left-click on the text to place the [text cursor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(user_interface)#Text_cursor) there, then press `Shift` and `Left/Right arrow keys` to select text.

This option available in other PDF readers such as AA Reader, but not sure if it's built in Okular